# How to hide popup box in HTML/Javascript when clicking anywhere on the screen (outside of popup)

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have written HTML/Javascript to show a popup box on the HTML page when the user clicks on a link. The popup works and can be closed by clicking on the x button. I want to add some functionality to also close the popup when the user clicks anywhere outside of the popup box.

Code is as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="popupLink" onclick="showPopup('This is test popup message'); return false;">poup test link</a>

  <div id="popupContainer" class="popup-container">
    <div id="popupContent" class="popup-content">
        <!-- Content for the popup -->
    </div>
    <button id="popupClose" class="close-button">&times;</button>
  </div>
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
function showPopup(content) {
    // Get the elements by their ID
    var popupLink = document.getElementById("popupLink");
    var popupContainer = document.getElementById("popupContainer");
    var popupWindow = document.getElementById("popupContent");
    var popupClose = document.getElementById("popupClose");
    // Set the content for the popup
    popupWindow.innerHTML = content;
    
    // Show the pop-up window
    popupContainer.style.display = "block";

    // Hide the pop-up window when the close button is clicked
    popupClose.addEventListener("click", function() {
        popupContainer.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

I have tried adding a document level event listener. But it is not working. After I add this, the popup does not show at all.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        // Check if the clicked element is not inside the popup and not the link that opens it
        if (!popupContainer.contains(event.target) && event.target !== popupLink && popupContainer.style.display === "block") {
            console.log("inside the if block")
            popupContainer.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```js
function showPopup(content) {
    var popupContainer = document.getElementById("popupContainer");
    var popupWindow = document.getElementById("popupContent");
    var popupClose = document.getElementById("popupClose");

    popupWindow.innerHTML = content;
    popupContainer.style.display = "block";

    popupClose.addEventListener("click", function() {
        popupContainer.style.display = "none";
    });

    document.addEventListener("click", closePopupOutside);
}

function closePopupOutside(event) {
    var popupLink = document.getElementById("popupLink");
    var popupContainer = document.getElementById("popupContainer");
    var popupWindow = document.getElementById("popupContent");

    if (!popupWindow.contains(event.target) && event.target !== popupLink) {
        popupContainer.style.display = "none";
        document.removeEventListener("click", closePopupOutside);
    }
}
```

```css
.popup-container {
    display: none;
}

/* Your styles for the popup */
```

```html
<a href="#" id="popupLink" onclick="showPopup('This is test popup message'); return false;">poup test link</a>

<div id="popupContainer" class="popup-container">
    <div id="popupContent" class="popup-content">
        <!-- Content for the popup -->
    </div>
    <button id="popupClose" class="close-button">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow the following only worked for me when I changed popupContainer to popupWindow. After this, it works flawlessly.

`if (!popupWindow.contains(event.target) && event.target !== popupLink) {`

Answer (score 0):

Here, since you're adding this event listener before the popup container is actually displayed, the popupContainer variable might not be accessible within the event listener's scope at that moment.

```js
function showPopup(content) {
    // Get the elements by their ID
    var popupLink = document.getElementById("popupLink");
    var popupContainer = document.getElementById("popupContainer");
    var popupWindow = document.getElementById("popupContent");
    var popupClose = document.getElementById("popupClose");
    // Set the content for the popup
    popupWindow.innerHTML = content;
    
    // Show the pop-up window
    popupContainer.style.display = "block";

    // Hide the pop-up window when the close button is clicked
    popupClose.addEventListener("click", function() {
        popupContainer.style.display = "none";
    });

    // Add document-level event listener to close popup when clicked outside
    document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        // Check if the clicked element is not inside the popup and not the link that opens it
        if (!popupContainer.contains(event.target) && event.target !== popupLink && popupContainer.style.display === "block") {
            popupContainer.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="popupLink" onclick="showPopup('This is test popup message'); return false;">poup test link</a>

<div id="popupContainer" class="popup-container">
   <div id="popupContent" class="popup-content">
        <!-- Content for the popup -->
   </div>
   <button id="popupClose" class="close-button">&times;</button>
</div>
```